# SQL - Ordering query by lastest date and then by ID

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
NotificationID  NotificationTypeID CreatedOn
5               2                  2020-01-27 10:05:33.147
4               13                 2020-01-24 15:56:04.437
3               3                  2020-01-24 14:16:53.327
2               2                  2020-01-24 14:16:53.327
1               1                  2020-01-22 15:12:38.663
```

I want it to be ordered by the CreatedOn field and then NotificationTypeID like this:

```
NotificationID  NotificationTypeID CreatedOn
5               2                  2020-01-27 10:05:33.147
2               2                  2020-01-24 14:16:53.327
4               13                 2020-01-24 15:56:04.437
3               3                  2020-01-24 14:16:53.327
1               1                  2020-01-22 15:12:38.663
```

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Notification.NotificationTypeID ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC) RowNumber,
    Notification.NotificationID,
    Notification.NotificationTypeID,
    CreatedOn
FROM Notification
ORDER BY RowNumber DESC, CreatedOn DESC
```

But it gives me the oldest value first:

```
NotificationID  NotificationTypeID CreatedOn
2               2                  2020-01-24 11:34:37.063
5               2                  2020-01-27 10:05:33.147
4               13                 2020-01-24 15:56:04.437
3               3                  2020-01-24 14:16:53.327
1               1                  2020-01-22 15:12:38.663
```

Comment: Your result is not ordered by CreatedOn and the by NotificationTypeID. Is it?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. There's no ordering in your result.

Comment: Updated with my SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
select NotificationID, NotificationTypeID, CreatedOn
from Notification
order by
    max(CreatedOn) over(partition by NotificationTypeID) desc,
    CreatedOn desc
```

This will put first the `NotificationTypeID` that has the greatest `CreatedOn`, and then order records that have the same `NotificationTypeID` by descending `CreatedOn`.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.

Comment: @Cheon: sorry, just fixed a typo (`desc` should be outside the window function)

Answer (score 0):

You can try order by with case

```
Order by CreatedOn desc, 
case when NotificationTypeID = 2 then 1
     when NotificationTypeID = 13 then 2
     when NotificationTypeID = 3 then 3
     when NotificationTypeID = 1 then 4 End
```